# Playing Sound Loop or Stoping Play with AudioServices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I created this method to easily play sounds in an XCode iPhone application.

```
void playSound(NSString* myString) {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    NSString *string = myString;
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (__bridge CFStringRef) string, CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

The problem with this is, I don't know how to later stop the sound or to make the sound play on a loop forever until it is stopped. How would I go about doing this? Could I possibly make the method return the sound, and then put that in a variable to later be modified?

Comment: I have always personally used AVAudioPlayer objects to handle sound, but I found a topic discussing something similar using AudioServices here. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4446-simple-sound-question.html - Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is also that you have to release the sound once you do not need it (AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID). So it requires you to manage resources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid i dont know how to stop it, but try this for looping:

```
soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AudioName" ofType:@"wav"]];
sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil];
sound.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite
[sound play];
```

Comment: [sound pause] to stop.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation: "The interface does not provide level, positioning, looping, or timing control, and does not support simultaneous playback...".

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference

So for sound playback it is better use AVFoundation classes.

Answer (score 1):

System Sound Services usually is used to play short sounds/alerts/etc and pausing/stopping probably should be avoided. If this is really needed you could try `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(systemSoundID)` to stop the sound.
As for looping you could create recursive function to loop the sound using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion`.

Example (swift 3):

```
func playSystemSound(systemSoundID: SystemSoundID, count: Int){
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(systemSoundID) {
        if count > 0 {
            self.playSystemSound(systemSoundID: systemSoundID, count: count - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

So in your example you would just replace `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);` with `playSystemSound(systemSoundID: soundID, count: numOfPlays)`

Comment: This will indeed trigger a loop, however the completion block is not run in sync with the sound completion so there is no guarantee that the sound will actually play the given number of times. System Sounds are not meant to be looped, use AVAudioPlayer instead and provide .numberOfLoops if you want to loop a sound

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to decide to play a sound based on a bool variable,

```
private func playSound() {
        if isStarted {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, {
                if self.isStarted {
                    self.playSound()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```